# Pandas - Criar coluna nova com contagem de ocorrências

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho um dataframe relativamente grande e gostaria de criar uma coluna chamada `contagem` com o número de ocorrências da mesma linha no mesmo dataframe, quando o valor de determinadas linhas for igual em determinadas colunas. 
De:

```
id | coluna1 | coluna2 | coluna3 | coluna4
0  | z       | x       | x       | a
1  | y       | y       | y       | b
2  |    x    |    x    |    x    | c
3  |    x    |    x    |    x    | d
4  | z       | y       | x       | e
5  |    w    |    w    |    w    | f
6  |    w    |    w    |    w    | g
7  |    w    |    w    |    w    | h
```

Para:

```
id | coluna1 | coluna2 | coluna3 | coluna4 | contagem
0  | z       | x       | x       | a       | 1
1  | y       | y       | y       | b       | 1
2  |    x    |    x    |    x    | c       | 2
3  |    x    |    x    |    x    | d       | 2
4  | z       | y       | x       | e       | 1
5  |    w    |    w    |    w    | f       | 3
6  |    w    |    w    |    w    | g       | 3
7  |    w    |    w    |    w    | h       | 3
```

Reparem que só usei as colunas 1, 2 e 3 no processo de contagem. Imagino que dê pra usar `groupby` pra isso, mas não sei como.

Comment: Porque o id = 1 contou 1 e o id = 2 contou 2? A linha de id=1 possui 3 letras `y` e o id=2 possui 3 letras `x`... Porque a diferença na contagem?

Comment: Porque ```x x x``` (id 2 e 3) aparece 2 vezes e ```y y y``` só 1 vez

Comment: Talvez isso facilite. A pergunta a ser feita é: quantas vezes os valores de ```coluna1```, ```coluna2``` e ```coluna3``` aparecem no dataframe? Não individualmente, mas os 3 juntos mesmo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A solução é realmente com `groupby`. Porém, é necessário usar o `transform`.

Veja abaixo:

### Criando dataframe de teste

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col_A": ["z", "y", "x", "x", "z", "w", "w", "w"], "col_B": ["x", "y", "x", "x", "y", "w", "w", "w"], "col_C": ["x", "y", "x", "x", "x", "w", "w", "w"], "col_D": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]})

df
  col_A col_B col_C col_D
0     z     x     x     a
1     y     y     y     b
2     x     x     x     c
3     x     x     x     d
4     z     y     x     e
5     w     w     w     f
6     w     w     w     g
7     w     w     w     h
```

### Gerando coluna contagem

```
df["contagem"] = df.groupby(["col_A", "col_B", "col_C"]).transform('size')

df
  col_A col_B col_C col_D  contagem
0     z     x     x     a         1
1     y     y     y     b         1
2     x     x     x     c         2
3     x     x     x     d         2
4     z     y     x     e         1
5     w     w     w     f         3
6     w     w     w     g         3
7     w     w     w     h         3
```

**Nota**: Ao invés de `size`, você pode optar pelo `count`. O resultado será o mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado, Paulo!

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, poderia dizer o motivo?